# First two links are not working while using angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a list grid using angularjs ng-repeat. Its displaying the list but the first two links are not working.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

  ..... ng-repeat="serviceprovider in model.Rows.....

<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 spg-info">
    <div class="row spg-info-row">
        <a ng-href="#/sp/details/{{ model.Name}}">{{model.Name}}</a>
    </div>
```

The links after the first two are working yet I am using the same code.

Comment: Could you please post all your code (including the JS part)?

Comment: whats not working ? 404 error ?

Comment: I have several components which are loaded on a html page using $stateprovider and ui-view. lets say I have a link like               <a ng-href="path">Take me somewhere</a>         in a component. Once the component is loaded, the link appears blue but does not function like a link on hover or click. It appears just like a label. If I have several links on the same component, its is the first two only not working. the rest are working fine. Inspecting the element shows that the link is coded correctly.

Comment: @PhilloPeters do not comment, instead edit the post.